# Function that replaces for loop counter Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, iterator, append

Is there a way of outputting the number of iterations without using the counter variable?

```
values= ["4","a","rk","sp"]
counter = 0 
for k in values:
    print("counter: ",counter, "value: ", k)
    counter +=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) would work well here:

```
values= ["4","a","rk","sp"]
for count, k in enumerate(values):
    print("counter: ", count, "value: ", k)
```

The purpose of `enumerate` it to supply an index or enumeration of the values of a iterable. That's basically what you're doing here.